# How to copy files from svn to linux

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm planning to write a script to copy the files from svn to my linux machine. But should i use `svn checkout` for this kind of operation or is it a easier way to copy the files to linux from svn?

I'm facing an issue here. Suppose i have 4 sub folders inside my parent1 reposritory say

```
http://..../Parent1
```

Parent1 has 4 subfolders.

```
Parent1 : sub1 sub2 sub3 sub4
```

Now i use the command svn checkout

```
svn checkout http://..../Parent1  MY_TEST_FOLDER
```

in MY_TEST_FOLDER i only have sub1 and sub3 checked out. sub2 and sub4 are not coming.

Comment: That's exactly what `svn checkout` is for.

Comment: So everytime I checkout something using svn checkout i also have to do a cleanup using svn cleanup?

Comment: I don't think so. Checkout doesn't lock the files.

Comment: Suppose I have 4 subfolders in the repository say [Please see my post edit]

Comment: Do you get any error messages or anything? How were those two folders added to the repository?

Comment: You can also have a look at `svn export`, which will, well, export instead of checkout, so you don't have the `.svn` folders. Are `sub1` and `sub3` really added _and committed_ to svn? What does `svn ls http://.../Parent1` say?

Answer (score 0):

For every object in SVN-repo you have to pay attention on two questions

- Physical presence of node
- Your (as SVN-user) permissions for this node: you may have none rights on it and for you it seems as missing object